# Cannot find rvm.sh in /etc/profile.d/

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am new to RVM and looking to use it as I deploy my Rails app to a Digital Ocean server.  I am following [this tutorial](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/rails-deployment/) and trying to get my Mina script to run (similar to Capistrano).  The script includes a set up section with these lines:

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm use || exit 1
```

Unfortunately, `rvm.sh` does not exist in `/etc/profile.d` (or anywhere else on my server).  `rvm` seems to be installed just fine (I can set list rubies, set my Ruby default version, etc).  I'm not even sure what `rvm.sh` would contain if it existed.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: does `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` exists on the installing user? - it can be used instead

Comment: @michal thank you so much for the comment - that is really nice of you.  You worked so hard to give us this great package and still spend time helping new users.  Your comment was a great clue - I installed `rvm` under my "main" user (the one I do everything from so I could disable root) but it is not installed for the user associated with the site I am deploying.  Do I need to reinstall `rvm` for each user?  I plan to use it for multiple Rails sites on this server.

Comment: For instance, should I uninstall `rvm` and reinstall as a multi-user install using [these instructions](http://ajacevedo.com/2013/rvm-multi-user-install/)?

Comment: it's so nice when ruby installations using rvm are sooo fast, simple and hassle free!...

Answer (score 0):

@mpapis got me on the right path here.  I had installed `rvm` under one user, but not for this user.  I wound up uninstalling `rvm` and starting from scratch, installing `rvm` for multiple users.